# Why does Utop treat this Ocaml code differently

Tags: module, ocaml, utop

```
module D = struct type t = float list end
module DF(D) = struct type t = D.t end
```

gets a syntax error in utop

However,

```
module D = struct type t = float list end;;
module DF(D) = struct type t = D.t end
```

Does not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utop ignores everything on the right of `;;` since `;;` signals the end of a toplevel phrase.

Comment: Do you know why it doesn't compile in the first place?

Comment: Non-empty functor argument requires both a name and a module type: `module DF(M:sig type t end) = struct type t = M.t end`.